# How to fix low webcam fps in VMware Fusion?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, webcam

I’m using the webcam passthrough feature in VMware Fusion. However, the frame rate is very low. How do I fix this? Or could this problem perhaps be solved using an external webcam?

### Problem:

- Integrated Webcam running on very low fps (<1)
- tried with Cheese (like Photo Booth, but for Linux) and VLC Player

### Host System:

- MacOS Big Sur

  - 2.4 GHz
  - 16gb ram
  - 256ssd

### VM:

- Vmware fusion 12.1.1
- running Ubuntu 18.04

  - 4 Processors
  - 10gb ram
  - 60gb ssd

Comment: Please [clarify your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1648046/edit). Are you asking how to fix this? What do you mean by “with external cameras”? Are you perhaps not using the integrated camera? If yes, does it behave differently on the integrated camera?

Comment: sorry for not being so specific. Yes I am asking how to fix this. I use the integrated webcam of my laptop and, in the future, I plan to use an external connected 3d camera.

Comment: I rewrote your question to actually ask what you want. Please check whether it’s okay like this.

Answer (score 1):

Certain cameras may not work well with virtual USB camera. Perform these steps to enable pass through of cameras in to virtual machine:

1. Ensure to shutdown all virtual machines and quit VMware Fusion if
   its running.
2. Open Terminal ( /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app)
3. Run this command to change the current location.

   ```
   cd ~/Library/Preferences/VMware\ Fusion/
   ```
4. Open the preferences file using vi or nano editors in terminal

   ```
   nano preferences
   ```
5. Add this parameter at the end of the file:

   ```
   vusbcamera.passthrough = "TRUE"
   ```
6. Save and close the preferences file.
7. Launch VMware Fusion and startup your virtual machine.
8. Important: Remove all existing camera devices.
9. (Optional) In some cases, you might want to change the USB compatibility to USB 3.0. It can be changed under "Advanced USB settings"
10. Click Virtual Machine menu > USB and Bluetooth Setting
11. Select the Camera you want from the list to connect it to the virtual machine.

This should improve your fps on the webcam. However, the problem is still remains unaddressed from VMWare. Check out the official thread [here.](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Webcam-performance-inside-VM/td-p/506546)

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119652/poor-fps-with-mac-webcam-when-used-on-ubuntu-on-vmware-fusion) askUbuntu question. Some people have also had luck switching to older versions of VMware.

Comment: Just want to comment that these instructions do work as they helped me update my Razer Kiyo preferences.

Just want to clarify for future readers, that when the @SkV says to "remove existing cameras", I had to remove them from the VM preferences + unplug the USB device from my Mac. 

Start the VM, and plug the usb device back in, and the camera appears in the usb devices menu.